# Clicking the navbar item using scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery

What should i replace to click this navbar called `security printing`? Im new with laravel.

```
$('.anotha').on('click', function () {
if ($(this).on(':clicked')) {
    $('#secur').clicked();
   }
})
```

I know its wrong code. But I tried

```
$('.anotha').on('click', function () {
if ($(this).on(':clicked')) {
    $('#secur').click();
   }
})
```

Nothing happened too, still the current active navbar is the `about us`

```
$('.anotha').on('click', function () {
if ($(this).on(':clicked')) {
    $('#secur').show();
}
});
```

Nothing happened because the tab-item is already showed. same as

```
$('.anotha').on('click', function () {
if ($(this).on(':clicked')) {
    $('#secur').select();
   }
})
```

and

```
$('.anotha').on('click', function () {
if ($(this).on(':clicked')) {
    $('#secur').selected();
   }
})
```

[image]

UPDATE:

When I remove the `if clause` the code will look like this:

```
$('.anotha').on('click', function () {
    $('#secur').selected();
})
```

Same as other code but nothing happened still.

Comment: I don't understand your if clause `if ($(this).on(':clicked'))`. Have you tried to remove it?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and not yet. I didn't tried it, I'll try it now

Comment: @Apollo79 I tried it now, I removed the `if ($(this).on(':clicked'))` still nothing happened.

Comment: Can you share the code with the removed if clause?

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] of your issue. We currently have no idea what your HTML looks like, and how the existing funtionality is actually implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every HTML element has a [`click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) method that can be called to simulate a mouse click.

```
    document.getElementById('#secur').click();
```

jQuery [provides it's own method](https://api.jquery.com/click/) that wraps this feature.

```
$('.anotha').on('click', function () {
    $('#secur').click();
})
```

By the way, this does not require jQuery to accomplish. The following code would be the equivalent in plain javascript.

```
let a = document.querySelectorAll('.anotha');
let s = document.querySelector('#secur');

a.forEach(x => {
    x.addEventListener('click', event => {
        s.click();
    });
});

s.addEventListener('click', event => {
    console.log('#secur was clicked');
});
```

Comment: This actually what I wanted to do, I didn't think that `non-jQuery` not going to work since I'm focusing more on `jQuery` functions. Thank you!